# Как в Handlebars повторно вывести данные без условий заданных ранее?

Tags: javascript, handlebars

Здраствуйте, есть json, необходимо с помощью Handlebars вывести сначала те записи которые имеет поле "favotite" затем абсолютно все записи, но если задан условие, то повторно выводится, эти же отфильтрованные записи.

json выглядит так:

```
{
    "list": [
        {
            "description": "admin",
            "favotite": "True"
        },
        {
            "description": "user 1"
        },
        {
            "description": "user 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

часть html выглядит так:

```
<h1>Favorite</h1>
    <ul class="character-list-container"></ul>
    <script id="character-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        {{#each list}}
        <li>
        {{#if favotite}}
            <h2>{{description}}</h2>
        {{/if}}
        </li>
        {{/each}}
    </script>

    <h1>All</h1>
    <ul class="character-list-container"></ul>
    <script id="character-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        {{#each list}}
        <li>
            <h2>{{description}}</h2>
        </li>
        {{/each}}
    </script>
```

Результат выходит такой:

```
Favorite
admin
All
admin
```

Но нужно что бы вывод был таким:

```
Favorite
admin
All
admin
user 1
user 2
```

Как можно это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

может такой вариант ?!

```html
{{#if list.[0].favotite}}
<h2>favotite</h2>
<span>{{list.[0].favotite}}</span> {{/if}}

<h2>description</h2>
{{#each list}}
<span>{{description}} </span> {{/each}}
```

**P.S:** если есть несколько  `"favotite": "True"`
можно так например:

```html
<h2>favotite</h2>
<ul>
  {{#each list}} {{#if this.favotite}}
  <li>{{this.description}}</li>
  {{/if}} {{/each}}
</ul>

<h2>All</h2>
<ul>
  {{#each list}}
  <li>{{description}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: не совсем, но уже видимо близко, там может быть несколько записей с "favotite" и будут забросаны по json файлу

Comment: @WhtFck добавил изменение - должно все хорошо работать